# Magento Cron Job Problem

Tags: cron, jobs

In Magento I have set the cron job to run every minute and I also created a cron job in the plesk control panel because the magento setup wasn't working for me.

So I created a cron job as follows:
/usr/bin/php -f /home/dealscou/public_html/cron.php

This works for me most of the time when the cron job is set to 1 minute. 
If I create a cron job for any other amount of time, it does not work.

I am really stuck on this and my customer is getting ticked that I can't fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Kathy

Comment: What does the cron settings look like that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You should run the cron from the cron.sh file and not directly from the cron.php file

Comment: Why exactly would you say that? The cron.sh simply calls the php binary and executes cron.php.

Comment: Since it's advised in the official Magento installation guide (source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job) ;)

Comment: I see. I only ask because the .sh file will do the same thing he is doing. The .sh call will most likely not resolve the issue. I HAVE to use the .php call because we have multiple versions of php on the system.